# Dynamic server path of my web site

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

i am working on a web site in php/mysql/jquerymobile

> all of my files are stored in MYSITE folder ( Working on WAMP) ( And
>   online www.MYSITE.com) i.e. MYSITE/images (www.MYSITE.com/images)
>   MYSITE/css(www.MYSITE.com/css), MYSITE/js(www.MYSITE.com/js) etc etc

in my script i need a variable which stores the static path of my root directory 
i.e.

```
$sitepath = "localhost/MYSITE";// (for local)
$sitepath = "www.MYSITE.com" ;//(for online webhosting)
```

i just need a script of code to get this path dynamically , if i am working either on WAMP or on Online .

> i have tried the following code but its not working fine

```
 $sitepath = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
and 
$sitepath = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; /// its not working on every machine...
```

Please help me.

Comment: This is called `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the document root and actual file path, then substring them:

> index.php

```
$server_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$root_path = __DIR__;

$web_path = substr($root_path, strlen($server_root));
if (substr($web_path, 0, 1) != '/') $web_path = '/' . $web_path;
if (substr($web_path, -1) != '/') $web_path = $web_path . '/';
```

So if your files are in /var/www/mysite and the server is serving files from /var/www, `$web_path` will be /mysite/ (your localhost). If the server is serving files from /var/www/mysite, `$web_path` will be '/' (your web host).

You can then load your CSS, JS, images and any other resources from `$web_path . "images/image.jpg"`

Note that this may need some tweaking if your site is being served from an Apache alias or from a folder that is symlinked somewhere else.

Comment: First of all thanks dear for your quick reply .. i have modified the code a little bit to solve my problem the changes are

 `$path = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$web_path;`
its working fine, if you could give me some more suggestion , i will appericiate it..

one more thing i want to ask is that i want to achieve it in **javascript  (in .js file)**